# How to solve error class file for com.jogamp.common.type.WriteCloneable not found

Tags: java, jogl

While compiling JOGL code, I am getting following error

> class file for com.jogamp.common.type.WriteCloneable not found

I also attached a screenshot of the error:
[image: screenshot with console with error message "class file for com.jogamp.common.type.WriteCloneable not found"]

Here is the code:

```
package com.jogamp.opengl;
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;   
import javax.swing.JFrame;    
    
public class HelloWorld implements GLEventListener {    
    
    @Override    
public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0)     
  {    
            
  }    
    
   @Override    
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {    
final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();    
  //Draw H  
gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINES);   
gl.glVertex2d(-0.8, 0.6);  
gl.glVertex2d(-0.8, -0.6);  
gl.glVertex2d(-0.8, 0.0);  
gl.glVertex2d(-0.4, 0.0);  
gl.glVertex2d(-0.4, 0.6);  
gl.glVertex2d(-0.4, -0.6);  
gl.glEnd();  
//Draw W  
gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_LINES);  
gl.glVertex2d(0.4,0.6);  
gl.glVertex2d(0.4,-0.6);  
gl.glVertex2d(0.4,-0.6);  
gl.glVertex2d(0.6,0);  
gl.glVertex2d(0.6,0);  
gl.glVertex2d(0.8,-0.6);  
gl.glVertex2d(0.8,-0.6);  
gl.glVertex2d(0.8,0.6);  
gl.glEnd();  
   }          
   @Override    
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4)     
   {        
    
   }    
   @Override    
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0)     
   {    
    
   }    
    
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    
final GLProfile gp = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);    
GLCapabilities cap = new GLCapabilities(gp);    
    
final GLCanvas gc = new GLCanvas(cap);    
HelloWorld sq = new HelloWorld();    
gc.addGLEventListener(sq);    
gc.setSize(400, 400);    
    
final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");    
frame.add(gc);    
frame.setSize(500,400);    
frame.setVisible(true);      
   }        
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Note: I downloaded jogl-all.jar file. Then I unzipped it. Then written the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download jogamp-fat.jar [here](https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.4.0-rc-20200307/fat/jogamp-fat.jar) (it's the latest release candidate in October 2020, otherwise, take [this one](https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/fat/jogamp-fat.jar) when it becomes more recent, typically when JOGL 2.4.0 or any later version is released).

Compile with:

```
javac -cp .:jogamp-fat.jar HelloWorld.java
```

Run with:

```
java -cp .:jogamp-fat.jar HelloWorld
```

You can find much more information in our official wiki [here](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE). Windows users must replace `:` by `;`. Using the fat JAR is easier and less error prone especially for newbies, it contains both the Java libraries and the native libraries of all JogAmp APIs (JOGL, JOCL, JOAL and GlueGen).

Comment: I did as per instruction mentioned above. Now Compilation is happened successfully. But there is error in execution. The error is         "Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld.Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opengl/HelloWorld (wrong name: HelloWorld) ".

Comment: In the mean time, I am exploring helps in official wiki link you shared.

Comment: Where is your class file HelloWorld.class?

Comment: 1: HelloWorld.java, 2: HelloWorld.class, 3: jogamp-fat.jar - all are at same location. I tried to put snapshot over here, no option found.

Comment: Please recompile without the line "package com.jogamp.opengl;" so that there is no package name involved.

Comment: You're welcome. When you use the package name "com.jogamp.opengl", your class file must be in com/jogamp/opengl and you must pass the package name to java: `java -cp .:jogamp-fat.jar com.jogamp.opengl.HelloWorld`. Don't forget to approve this answer if it's ok for you.

Comment: @Satadru Please can you approve my answer so that the beginners see the least misleading answer first here?

Comment: Last time tried to approve your answers. But i could not find any option. Please let me know how to approve answers.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23139/387101 "Click the check mark under this post, on the left"

Comment: @gouessej Instead of using the fat jar, is it possible for you and/or Sven to upload one of the release candidates on your repository? There is a version hosted on Jzy3D, but while a lot of the RC for 2.3.X have been made available, it is not the case for 2.4.0 (as can be seen here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all?repo=jogamp). Making a version available instead of the fat jar would make testing and deployment easier I believe (and better than using a 3rd party-hosted RC)

Comment: Maybe I could put it into https://jogamp.org/deployment/maven/ or https://jogamp.org/deployment/maven-test/ I'm currently very busy but I agree with your suggestion, it would help in the meantime until the new version is released. However, keep in mind that several build tools (Ant, Gradle, ...) allow to use the fat JAR as is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include [gluegen-rt lib](https://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/rc/v2.4.0-rc-20200307/jar/gluegen-rt.jar) to compile your class.

Also, you don't need to unzip jar files.

Use `-cp` variable to add a jar library to your [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html):

```
javac -cp .:gluegen-rt.jar:jogl-all.jar HelloWorld.java
```

To run your example you also need native extensions. You can find them [here](https://jogamp.org/deployment/archive/rc/v2.4.0-rc-20200307/jar/)

**Note**: Use the latest JOGL libraries especially if you use the latest Mac OS version.

```
java -cp .:gluegen-rt.jar:jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar:jogl-all.jar:gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar  HelloWorld
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried same as you suggested. I get following error   " error: error reading gluegen-rt.jar; zip END header not found "